# Error while parsing a feed due to a whitespace in XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

In one part of my app, I'm using this code to read a RSS feed:

```
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){...
```

The problem is that one of the feeds that I want to read starts whith a whitespace just before the `<?xml` just like that

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- generator="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" -->
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

When my app tries to read this feed throw the following error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: processing instructions must not start with xml (position:unknown  @1:2 in java.io.InputStreamReader@605667c)

Now my doubt is: how can I avoid this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure with the structure of response you can use skip() method of InputStream. Find below the code snippet.

```
Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream().skip(1));
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
```

Else convert the InputStream to String. You can use Apache IOUtils.
Process the String and then parse the xml.

Comment: The problem is that I use this code to read different feeds, but only one have this problem. In the other hand, when I try to add skip(1) appears this error: "The method parse(InputStream) in the type DocumentBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (long)"

Comment: try skip(1l). By default 1 will be cosidered as Integer. So use 1l instead.

Comment: If you use the same code to read different feeds the better option is to covert the response to String and use trim() function.

Comment: I added "l" and "L" and the problem is the same: "The method parse(InputStream) in the type DocumentBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (long)"

Comment: Maybe the option of convert the xml to a string and parse the feed from there is a good idea. Do you know where can I find any tutorial about that?

Comment: simply use the below line: Document dom = builder.parse(IOUtils.toString(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

Comment: I supose that I have to add a library to implement this code, haven't it? Because appears that error "IOUtils cannot be resolved"

Comment: Yes. Include apache io library. You can download it from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4